# How are game difficulty levels programmed in TD gammon?

Tags: machine-learning, unsupervised-learning, games, reinforcement-learning, artificial-intelligence

I understand that Temporal Difference player is trained by making it play against itself. In such a case, how are game difficulty levels programmed?

Can fewer training iterations successfully create weaker players? Or just incompletely trained players?

Answer (score 4):

I think that using not fully trained agents for difficulty below grandmaster might be hard to do, because the designer of training process has to focus both on creating the "best" agent in the end AND setting the right cutoffs in between. Given the often stochastic nature of balancing exploration and exploitation during the learning (e.g. by using $\epsilon$-greedy policies), the intermediate agents might be not stable.

Instead I think it would be easier to first learn the state($s$)-action($a$)-value-function $Q(s,a)$ for the best agent and then try to adjust the parameters in such a way, that suboptimal actions are selected (by e.g. selecting an action with lesser $Q(s,a)$ or reducing the lookahead in heuristic search, resulting in next-best-action without taking long-term-effects into account).

How to set the threshold for the different difficulty levels, i.e. what is "easy" etc., is a subject on its own (Game Design). The best agent defines the grandmaster level, but how many games should a beginner be able to win on average to define the lowest difficulty level ?

**Disclaimer** 
I have only read the [summary of TD-Gammon](https://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~sutton/book/ebook/node108.html) in the book *Reinforcement Learning: An Introduction* by Sutton and Barto, not the full paper.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to selecting suboptimal actions as steffen mentioned, you can act on the following parameters when training TD-Gammon:

- number of games TD-Gammon was trained on
- number of units used in the hidden layer
- whether to use a 1-ply search, 2-ply search, 3-ply search, etc.
- which human-engineered feature to use

From http://videolectures.net/rldm2015_silver_reinforcement_learning/?q=reinforcement%20learning (David Silver):

[image]

The neural network that was used (image taken from http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~sutton/book/ebook/node108.html):

[image]

Comment: I'll go through the video lecture, but is TD in TD gammon not Temporal Difference? How did the hidden layer come into the picture? I was of the impression that TD - would mean a state space with random weights that are refined with training. The state space is large and exhaustive. Did I start off with a wrong understanding of TD gammon?

Reinforcement learning, TD = unsupervised learning with feedback from the environment. 

Neural networks, hidden layers, back propagation = supervised learning. Feeback is the difference between correct and achieved values.