# Can a machine learning model be trained to not be optimal?

Tags: machine-learning

I am thinking about AI bots in strategy games, let's say chess. The concept to train a model to choose always the movement most likely to end in victory is intuitive, even if it is not easy to implement. How can we train a model to be suboptimal, and let the human player choose difficulty settings? A badly implemented model could work as an easy settings, but butchering the training set doesn't seem right.

Comment: There may be ways of doing this, but if you want a specific answer you will need to ask a specific question. For ex. using neural networks, you could stop the building before the loss function stabilizes. Another way would be to introduce probability in the game, sometimes choosing the optimal path, sometimes choosing a random path.

Comment: I think ai.stackexchange has some discussion on similar topics, check it out. I would think that the training is to optimize some sort of engagement metric, not win rate per se

Comment: Another option, assuming your AI has a model of the game, is to modify its planning based on difficulty. For example, in chess AI, there's usually some sort of monte carlo search. You can expand/shorten the search depth and width to control the difficulty as well.

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/174762/how-are-game-difficulty-levels-programmed-in-td-gammon/187752